# How to convert a column to a row (Python)

Tags: python

I would like to transform a file that contains one column of numbers (many numbers) like:

```
1

2

3
...

i
```

to a one-dimensional list such as `[1, 2, 3, ...i]`.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are the lines separated by blank lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: read file line by line into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)

Answer (score 1):

Just read the lines of the file, strip the newlines of the ends, and cast to integers:

```
with open('text.txt') as text:
    data = [int(i.strip()) for i in text if i != '\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    nums = file.readlines()
nums = [i.rstrip('\n') for i in nums]
```

The second line is to ensure that the newlines are excluded from the list elements when you print `nums`.

If your file includes blanks, you need to also add this line to exclude empty strings from the final list:

```
nums = [int(i) for i in nums if i]
```

if you need to multiply list elements by a factor, say 0.7, you can rewrite the last line like this:

```
nums = [int(i) * 0.7 for i in nums if i]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However the numbers appears like ['1', '2', '3'...] instead of [1, 2, 3...]. Also is it possible to multiply them with 0.7 before listing? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that, it really helped. Do you know why when I save it as np.savetxt('freqline.dat', nums) is still shows column format?

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I have fixed it by adding float in front. So the code looks like this at the moment:

```
with open('freq.dat', 'r') as file:
File = file.readlines()
nums = np.array(File)
nums = [i for i in nums if i]
nums = [float(i.rstrip('\n')) for i in nums]

print nums
np.savetxt('freqline.dat', nums)
```

Any tips how to multiply the numbers with a specific value lets say 0.7. It prints the numbs [1,2,3...] now but in the saved text they are still in column format. Any suggestion how to change that?